# Meaning of nils in font-lock-defaults

Tags: font-lock, documentation

I want to understand the fields in `font-lock-defaults`. The documentation reads

> Defaults for Font Lock mode specified by the major mode.
> Defaults should be of the form:
>
> (KEYWORDS [KEYWORDS-ONLY [CASE-FOLD [SYNTAX-ALIST ...]]])
>
> KEYWORDS may be a symbol (a variable or function whose value is the keords
> to use for fontification) or a list of symbols (specifying different levels
> of fontification).
>
> If KEYWORDS-ONLY is non-nil, syntactic fontification (strings and
> comments) is not performed.
>
> If CASE-FOLD is non-nil, the case of the keywords is ignored when fontifying.
>
> If SYNTAX-ALIST is non-nil, it should be a list of cons pairs of the form
> (CHAR-OR-STRING . STRING) used to set the local Font Lock syntax table, for
> keyword and syntactic fontification (see ‘modify-syntax-entry’).

When I look at `font-lock-defaults` for Python and Elisp mode, I see the following values.

**Question:** What do the **four `nil`'s** mean in the Python and Elisp modes? I am not understanding how to match the elements of the list below to the documentation.

- Python

```lisp
((python-font-lock-keywords-level-1
  python-font-lock-keywords-level-1 
  python-font-lock-keywords-level-2
  python-font-lock-keywords-maximum-decoration)
 nil nil nil nil
 (font-lock-syntactic-face-function . python-font-lock-syntactic-face-function))
```

- Elisp

```lisp
((lisp-el-font-lock-keywords
  lisp-el-font-lock-keywords-1
  lisp-el-font-lock-keywords-2)
 nil nil nil nil
 (font-lock-mark-block-function . mark-defun)
 (font-lock-extra-managed-props help-echo)
 (font-lock-syntactic-face-function . lisp-font-lock-syntactic-face-function))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, look at the source code. This variable is defined in `font-core.el`, so it is a good bet that the code which uses the variable is also in that file. A quick search turns up the function `font-lock-set-defaults` in `font-lock.el`, which grovels through the various things stored in this variable and does something with each one. By reading that code, including some comments in it, we can deduce what everything is for.

| nth | docstring | variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | KEYWORDS | keywords |
| 1 | KEYWORDS-ONLY | font-lock-keywords-only |
| 2 | CASE-FOLD | font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search |
| 3 | SYNTAX-ALIST | font-lock-syntax-table |
| 4 |  | font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function |
| 5… | Further item elements are alists of the form… | alist |

So why isn’t `font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function` mentioned in the docstring? Well, there is a comment that explains:

```lisp
;; (nth 4 defaults) used to hold `font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function',
;; but that was removed in 25.1, so if it's a cons cell, we assume that
;; it's part of the variable alist.
```

The values of this variable for various modes simply predates the change that removed the `font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function` variable, and they just didn’t bother to change every single mode that sets this variable (because that’s a lot of modes). Instead they made the code check to see if it’s there and skip over it if it is.